# Christoffel symbols and metric determinant

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I am looking at a special class of space-time where the Christoffel symbols obey $$\Gamma^a_{bc} = g_{bc}g^{ad}\partial_d\ln \sqrt{g}$$ I wish to know if such class of space-times have been seen or studied before?

Comment: by $G_{ab}$ you mean the space-time metric $g_{ab}$?

Comment: @Pinkman98 Yes.